# My Contact Activity page is showing up blank after adding main activity and a button

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

So I've managed to stop my android app from crashing. I run the contract activity as the launched activity and it shows up with our bar on top, where our name is. In the interest of app user interaction I've created a main activity with a button. When I press that button it leads to the contactActivity but now its coming up blank, no logo or anything. In order to get it to run I had to change the main theme to appCompat. But that the only change I've made.

Here is the style.xml

```
 <resources
     <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">

     <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/dsrpt_background</item>

    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>

    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/dsrpt_textcolor</item>
    </style>
 </resources>
```

And here is the main activity: All I want to do is see the same contact page a had before I added a main activity. Do I need to use appCompat as a theme?

```
package com.dysrupts.atom;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.content.Intent;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

        button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity( new Intent (MainActivity.this,ContactActivity.class));
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your layout

Comment: Is there any error showing up in the xml edit screen

Comment: Not that i've noticed